# Unable to pass object by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

I am creating object Expense in one class:

```
Expense exp(expense);
```

And then passing it to another class (Category) as a reference:

```
vector<Category> *ptrCateg = &(impl->categories);
ptrCateg->at(pos).addNewExpense(exp);
```

Here is how I recieve it in Category class:

```
void Category::addNewExpense(const Expense &exp){
   }
```

Here is how I defines addNewExpense method in header file:

```
void addNewExpense(const Expense &exp);
```

I am unable to figure out why I get an error here: `void Category::**addExpense**(const Expense &exp){`. It says: "Error: declaration is incompatible with "void ExpenseManager::Category::addNewExpense(const  &exp)" (declared at line 29 of "mycomputerandsonon\Category.h")".

I have googled endlessly about this, and I can't figure out what is wrong. I found an example of passing objects by references and yet I get this error...

Comment: A simple, compilable "main()" program would have been a good idea. I suspect the declaration of the method "addExpense" in the class is not the same as the definition outside the class.

Comment: No specific `with` subtext to that "Declaration is incompatible" message, as in "Declaration is in compatible with more-text-here"?

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry about that. The full description: "Error: declaration is incompatible with "void ExpenseManager::Category::addNewExpense(const <error-type> &exp)" (declared at line 29 of "mycomputerandsonon\Category.h")"

Comment: And `ExpenseManager` is a simple namespace? Or is it a enclosing class? Is `Expense` part of the same namespace? That message suggests `Expense` is not part of the same namespace, yet it is in the header file.

Comment: ExpenseManager is a simple namespace, and Expense is a part of it.

Comment: OK, so that should be easily reproducible in a stand-alone complete sample. Your implementation mentions nothing about a namespace, and has no qualifiers suggesting it is within one, nor is any mentioned. Technically that implementation should be `void ExpenseManager::Category::addNewExpense(const ExpenseManager::Expense& exp)`

Comment: Okay, but how can I fix this :/ Edit: nevermind, Etherealone helped me to figure this out :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header file provided in the comments, the file where `Expense` is declared is not included in Category.h. You should at least forward declare `Expense` (actually, *do* forward declare instead of unnecessary inclusion to avoid making compliation slow). You can do it by adding `class Expense;` before `class Category {...`.

Comment: Not really, no... I edited methods name recently, and updated information in stackoverflow (here) and it took me a while to edit everything. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Fractal Now that I read carefully the problem is about `Expense`. Is `Expense` declaration included in Category.h? Is the declarations in Category.h inside `ExpenseManager` namespace?

Comment: thank you for your time :) I believe so, here is my header file: http://pastebin.com/j0A6nheT

Comment: @Fractal The file where Expense is declared is not included in Category.h. You should at least forward declare Expense (actually do forward declare instead of unnecessary inclusion). You can do it by adding `class Expense;` before `class Category {...`.

Comment: Am I the only one that wonders what `// other includes` actually *includes* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I think they stand as separators, not censored includes.

Comment: @Etherealone I think not, as there is no `#include <string>`, etc in this header, yet it is used extensively in the declaration. I suspect there is a `#include` that is sucking in Expense incorrectly (i.e. out of namespace perhaps) but we'll never know.

Comment: @Fractal Ok. I see it tucked in there amongst the other prep roc directives. I stand (sit actually) corrected on that regard. Still wondering how `Expense` even compiled unless it was somehow brought in by one of the `#include` directives summarily replaced with `// other includes`